# R Program Vector, record Column Percent

Tags: r, vector, percentage

This is my vector

```
head(sep)
```

[image]

I must find percent of all SEP 11 in each row.

For instance, in first row, percent of SEP 11 is

```
100 * ((63 + 124)/ (63 + 124 + 0 + 0))
```

And would like this stored in newly created 8th column

Thanks

## dput

```
> dput(head(sep))
structure(list(Site = structure(1:6, .Label = c("31R001", "31R002", 
"31R003", "31R004", "31R005", "31R006", "31R007", "31R008", "31R011", 
"31R013", "31R014", "31R016", "31R018", "31R019", "31R020", "31R021", 
"31R022", "31R023", "31R024", "31R025", "31R026", "31R027", "31R029", 
"31R030", "31R031", "31R032", "31R034", "31R035", "31R036", "31R038", 
"31R039", "31R040", "31R041", "31R042", "31R043", "31R044", "31R045", 
"31R046", "31R048", "31R049", "31R050", "31R051", "31R052", "31R053", 
"31R054", "31R055", "31R056", "31R057", "31R058", "31R059", "31R060", 
"31R061", "31R069", "31R071", "31R072", "31R075", "31R435", "31R440", 
"31R445", "31R450", "31R455", "31R460", "31R470", "31R600", "31R722", 
"31R801", "31R825", "31R826", "31R829", "31R840", "31R843", "31R861", 
"31R880"), class = "factor"), Latitude = c(33.808874, 33.877256, 
33.820825, 33.852373, 33.829697, 33.810274), Longitude = c(-117.844048, 
-117.700135, -117.811845, -117.795516, -117.787532, -117.830429
), Windows.SEP.11 = c(63L, 174L, 11L, 85L, 163L, 71L), Mac.SEP.11 = c(0L, 
1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 50L), Windows.SEP.12 = c(124L, 185L, 9L, 75L, 
23L, 5L), Mac.SEP.12 = c(0L, 1L, 32L, 1L, 0L, 50L)), .Names = c("Site", 
"Latitude", "Longitude", "Windows.SEP.11", "Mac.SEP.11", "Windows.SEP.12", 
"Mac.SEP.12"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to get the `rowSums` of columns that have 'Windows' as column names, we subset the dataset ("sep1") using `grep`.  Then get the `rowSums(Sub1)`, divide by the `rowSums` of all the numeric columns (`sep1[4:7]`), multiply by 100, and assign the results to a new column ("newCol")

```
 Sub1 <- sep1[grep("Windows", names(sep1))]
 sep1$newCol <- 100*rowSums(Sub1)/rowSums(sep1[4:7])
```